# JQUERY get the first item from an array

Tags: jquery

```
$("canvas[name=myCanvas]").index(0).width( $(window).width() );
$("canvas[name=myCanvas]").index(0).height( $(window).height() );
```

Hello I have three canvas on a page. How can I set up only the first canvas width and height? 
And how can I access the third?

Tried:

```
$("canvas[name=myCanvas]").index(0)
```

and

```
$("canvas[name=myCanvas]")[0]
```

not worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the method [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

`$("canvas[name='myCanvas']").eq(0).width(...).height(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$($("canvas[name=myCanvas]").index(0)).width( $(window).width() );
$($("canvas[name=myCanvas]").index(0)).height( $(window).height() );
```

or

```
$($("canvas[name=myCanvas]")[0]).width( $(window).width() );
$($("canvas[name=myCanvas]")[0]).height( $(window).height() );
```

Comment: `$($("canvas[name=myCanvas]").index(0))`: double wrapping slows down extremely!

Answer (score 1):

both options are fine: `.index(0)` or `[0]`. The problem is that these return an html element not a jQuery object. Therefore, you cannot use the functions `width()` and `height()`

You can use `eq()` or convert the html objects into jquery with `$`, but the best option is to get this through selectors:

```
$("canvas[name=myCanvas]:first-child").width( $(window).width() ).height( $(window).height() );
```

or

```
$("canvas[name=myCanvas]:nth-child(0)").width( $(window).width() ).height( $(window).height() );
```